# Convert JavaScript number n to string s such that Object.is(eval(s), n) for all n?

Tags: javascript, floating-point, type-conversion, numbers, language-lawyer

I need to convert arbitrary JavaScript numbers to strings containing JavaScript expressions which are guaranteed to evaluate to the same value as the original number.

In general, `String()` does fine for most values, but notably `String(-0)` returns `'0'`, and though `0 === -0`, `Object.is(0, -0)` returns false.

Are there other number values `n` for which `eval(String(n))` does not return the value `n`?  I'm thinking particularly of cases where a floating point number cannot be exactly expressed in decimal, and the representation `String()` choses evaluates to a nearby but different floating point number due to rounding / insufficient precision.

If so, how can I obtain a `eval`-able string representation of these numbers?

Comment: You have to take care of `-0`, `Infinity`, and `NaN`. Note that the latter two are properties of the global object, which can theoretically be shadowed. Beware of scenarios like `{ let Infinity = 0; console.log(eval(Infinity)); }` (e.g. by accessing the global object with an indirect `eval` call, when you are using it anyways). I don't think there will be issues for other values, but i am super tired and therefore won't guarantee anything.

Comment: Your point about shadowing is well-taken, but `Infinity`, `-Infinity` and `NaN` are all handled just fine by `String()`.  The values I'm worried about are floating-point values for which `eval(String(x)) !== x` (if any exist).

Comment: Just to be clear: this question is mostly about the exactness / reversibility of the algorithms used by `Number.prototype.toString` and `eval`.

Comment: See "NOTE 1" on [7.1.12.1 NumberToString](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-tostring-applied-to-the-number-type). I didn't yet figure out whether there is a hidden trap between the parsing of literals and parsing of strings to numbers, but i highly doubt it. I'd pretty much conclude that apart from `-0` (as mentioned in the note) and shadowing issues or related, it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-0` is the only exception. To quote [the spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-tostring-applied-to-the-number-type) (NOTE 1):

> If x is any Number value other than -0, then ToNumber(ToString(x)) is exactly the same Number value as x.

Note that the behaviour of `String(x)` is to simply call `ToString(x)` when `x` is anything other than a Symbol ([spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-string-constructor-string-value)).

No precision is ever lost when converting a number to a string. It may be in a different format than the original, but it will always represent the same number:

```js
console.log( String(1e2) );
console.log( Object.is(1e2,100) );
```

As @ASDFGerte mentioned, `Infinity`, and `NaN` could be shadowed. So you may want to also add exceptions for `Infinity`, `-Infinity`, and `NaN`. Maybe something like:

```js
function reversibleNumberToString( x ) {
  if ( Object.is( -0, x ) )
    return '-0';
  const str = String(x);
  switch ( str ) {
    case 'Infinity':
      return '1/0';
    case '-Infinity':
      return '-1/0';
    case 'NaN':
      return '0/0';
    default:
      return str;
  }
}

// Tests
[ 0, 1, Math.random( ), -Infinity, Infinity, NaN ].forEach( x => {
  const Infinity = 'shadowed';
  console.log( Object.is( x, eval( reversibleNumberToString( x ) ) ) );
} );
```

Answer (score -5):

With the function Number

for example:

```
Number('0') === 0 // true
```

Comment: I'm trying to convert numbers into strings.  `Number` does the opposite.